# Does the streamWrite Function from pyspark, only run concurenttly and not in parellel?

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

So i have 3 streaming dataframes, where i've done some sort of transformation and now trying to write those 3 dataframes to their respective delta tables.

```
transformed_geo_df.writeStream \
  .format("delta") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/kinesis/_checkpoints/") \
  .table("12e255fc4fcd_geo_table")
```

What i've noticed is that the previous two writestreams aren't invoked, only the most current write stream is performed. Wondering how i can have all three running in parellel.

Further, I'm not sure if this makes a difference but i'm doing it on the databricks platform?

Comment: How do you deduce that writestream #3 is processing, not the previous 2?

Comment: @CliffordCheefoon the table with the sample data being written into has no updates as in says for example, updated 8 hours ago where as #3 says updated a few seconds ago

Comment: @CliffordCheefoon it might even be a delay on the catalog side of things of databricks